# How to call a function from a function appscript webapp

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to call a function from another function by passing parameters in google appscript. Kindly let me know if I have applied correct syntax here? Function runnCode is working , however updateDemoColors is not working which should change the class of an item of html

```js
<script>
  //google.script.run.updateColors();
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",runnCode);
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("enter",runnCode);
 
  function runnCode(){
      var fcolor = document.getElementById("color-1-hex").value;
      var bgcolor = document.getElementById("color-2-hex").value;

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ratio => {
        
        //document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = result;
        var n = 1/ratio;
        var actualRatio = n.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("ratio").innerHTML = actualRatio + ":1";
      }).calculateRatio(fcolor,bgcolor);
      
      // google.run.script.updateDemoColors(fcolor, bgcolor);
    google.script.run.updateBoxesColors(fcolor,bgcolor);
      
}
 function updateBoxesColors(colorFront, colorBack) {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ratio => {
    
    document.querySelectorAll("#aa-normal").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
    document.querySelectorAll("#aa-large").className   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : "fail";
    document.querySelectorAll("#aaa-normal").className = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : "fail";
    document.querySelectorAll("#aaa-large").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
    
    const totalWrong = document.querySelectorAll(".fail").length;
    let mouth = document.querySelectorAll("#mouth");
    let smile = document.querySelectorAll("#smile");

    switch(totalWrong) {
      case 0:
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,149  125,149  116,149 109,142 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,144 C 140,144 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,144 125,144 Z");
        
        break;
      case 1:
      case 2:
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,146  125,146  116,146 109,142 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,141 C 140,141 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,141 125,141 Z");
        
        break;
      case 3: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  140,143  125,143  110,143 109,138 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,138 C 140,138 143.5,132 143.5,132 143.5,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,138 125,138 Z");
        break;
      case 4: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  134,142  125,142  116,142 109,138 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,135 C 140,135 143,132 143,132 143,135 125,136 125,136 125,136 106.5,135 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,135 125,135 Z");
        
        break;
    }


    }).calculateRatio(colorFront,colorBack);

}
</script>
```

I am new to appscript and I have learnt that we can call a function by google.run.script.functionName and if the function is returning some value then we can call the function with successhandler. Have applied both above, however required output is not appearing on my webapp

```
function updateDemoColors(colorFront, colorBack) {

  google.run.script.withSuccessHandler({ 
    const demo = document.querySelector("#sample-text");
    demo.style.color = `rgb(${colorFront.toString()})`;
    demo.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${colorBack.toString()})`; 
    });
  
}
```

Comment: `updateDemoColors is not working which should change the class of an item of html`. If you are calling it via `google.script.run`, it's a server side function. If it's a server side function, it cannot change the class of an HTML element. Can you provide the code related to `updateDemoColors`? Most likely you just need to bring the function to the client-side, and call it without `google.script.run`. Same goes for `updateBoxesColors`, don't call it with `google.script.run`, that's for server-side functions.

Comment: Added code for updateDemoColors as well. Ok if we should not call the function with google.run.script. then please let me know how should I call these functions as I would need to fetch html elements in these funcntions as well with document.queryselect..

Comment: Just call them, without prepending `google.script.run` to it. If it's data from the HTML that you are getting, you don't need to go server-side. The other thing is, if you want to make sure the function runs after the server-side function `calculateRatio` returns, call it inside your success handler. Does this make sense to you?